# Mark as an Answer By the Community

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer

There's a lot of answers that are really good and have a lot of Up Votes, but the user that make the question never marked it as Correct, there's a way that the community mark the answer as [Accepted]?

e.g. An answer have more than 10 Up-votes and It has been more than a month since the answer was made, and there's no feedback from the person who asked the question, some user (an excavator) could flag the answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need.

"Accepted" means that the answer worked *for the original asker*.

Lots of upvotes meant that the *community agreed with a particular answer*.